# How can I calculate a moving average in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I have to add a moving average to my program which is working now with ultrasonic sensor with Arduino.

[First screen of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfHbE.png)

[Second screen of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niM7L.png)

[The third screen of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y35a.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please replace the images of code with the code itself and use the formatting tools in the editor to display the code correctly. This is because images are not searchable, accessible, and anyone wanting to help can't copy the text and try it out, they would have to retype it.

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code.  And, how is moving average for arduino different from any other?  Get it working on a PC platform first, then understand it.  Then transfer to arduino.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following code will help you:

```
//Parameters
const int aisPin  = A0;
const int numReadings  = 10;
int readings [numReadings];
int readIndex  = 0;
long total  = 0;

//Variables
int aisVal  = 0;

void setup() {
  //Init Serial USB
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("Initialize System"));
  //Init AnalogSmooth
  pinMode(aisPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  readAnalogSmooth();
  Serial.print(F("ais avg : ")); Serial.println(smooth());
  delay(200);
}

void readAnalogSmooth( ) { /* function readAnalogSmooth */
  ////Test routine for AnalogSmooth
  aisVal = analogRead(aisPin);
  Serial.print(F("ais val ")); Serial.println(aisVal);
}

long smooth() { /* function smooth */
  ////Perform average on sensor readings
  long average;
  // subtract the last reading:
  total = total - readings[readIndex];
  // read the sensor:
  readings[readIndex] = analogRead(aisPin);
  // add value to total:
  total = total + readings[readIndex];
  // handle index
  readIndex = readIndex + 1;
  if (readIndex >= numReadings) {
    readIndex = 0;
  }
  // calculate the average:
  average = total / numReadings;

  return average;
}
```

The basic concept is the same, keep a fixed window size and shift the window after each reading.

Note: Please change the above code according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to implement a moving/sliding average. One simple one that I've implemented is below, which works much the same way as HARSH's that he posted in his previous answer. This function, though, is a little more generic and can be used as-is for any data source and you can test it out on any platform. It also handles the startup case when values are first being populated. It is specific, though, to one source. So if you need a moving average for each of multiple sources, you'll have to duplicate the function or modify it to handle multiple sets of data. This uses `float` values for the data. Even if your data is integer, I'd suggest leaving the averaging data as `float`. Again, this is a simple averaging where all data values in the window have the same weight.

```
float movingAverage(float value) {
  const byte nvalues = 8;             // Moving average window size

  static byte current = 0;            // Index for current value
  static byte cvalues = 0;            // Count of values read (<= nvalues)
  static float sum = 0;               // Rolling sum
  static float values[nvalues];

  sum += value;

  // If the window is full, adjust the sum by deleting the oldest value
  if (cvalues == nvalues)
    sum -= values[current];

  values[current] = value;          // Replace the oldest with the latest

  if (++current >= nvalues)
    current = 0;

  if (cvalues < nvalues)
    cvalues += 1;

  return sum/cvalues;
}
```

The way you use it is fairly simple. Instead of calling, for example:

```
x = analogRead(DATA_PIN);
```

You would call:

```
x = movingAverage(analogRead(DATA_PIN));
```

And the `movingAverage` function does the rest for you. Inside the `movingAverage` function, you'll see a `const` value that defines the number of values used in the average. In the above case, it's 8.

You can use `movingAverage` on any sequence of values, so it doesn't have specific code inside it for reading pins. The way the `movingAverage` function works is that it keeps track of the last `nvalues` count of values you call it with and always returns the rolling average of those. It also avoids summing all the values in the window on each call by using a "delta" technique for the sum.

Answer (score -1):

Is that better than using Avg := (New + (N-1)*Avg) / N ?
no data storage is required.
When N=1 Avg = New
When N=111 Avg is LowPassFiltered
just tune N to get the required results
For fast startup one can just kludge in some startup code
IF Avg = 0 THEN Avg := New.
Boom instantly seeded...
Now of course if one gets unlucky and happens to seed it with a transient spike... then it will take a while to average that down